# The definition of $W_0^{1,\infty}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I know how to define $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subset R^N$ open bounded smooth boundary, for any $1\leq p<\infty$. However, for definition of $W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, I always confused. Recently I am studying a research topic consult about Quasi-convex function, i.e., the function $f$: $R^{d\times N}\to R$ satisfies
$$f(\xi)\leq \int_\Omega f(\xi+\nabla \phi(x))\,dx  $$
for all $\phi(x)\in W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega; R^d)$.

For example, we could find this definition in Dacorogna's book. However, Dacorogna never specific the definition of $W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega;R^d)$. But I was keep wondering that what should be the proper definition of $W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega;R^d)$. Should we just take $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega;R^d)$ and consider the closure in $W^{1,\infty}$ norm? I don't think so because this will make $W_0^{1,\infty}$ necessary to be in $C^1(\Omega)$, too strong.

I then find an definition in Leoni's book it states that we may use the $W^{1,\infty}$ weak-star closure instead of $W^{1,\infty}$ norm closure. But I failed the see what function do I have if I use $W^{1,\infty}$ weak-star closure. Do I still have $T[u]=0$? where $T$ is the trace operator.

Comment: You get Lipschitz functions.

Comment: @DeaneYang, the OP seems to be aware that $W^{1,\infty}$ functions are Lipschitz. To my understanding the question is about the boundary values: Is the weak-star closure of compactly supported smooth functions the same as the space of Lipschitz functions that vanish on the boundary?

Comment: The answer is yes. And you still have trace equal to zero.

Comment: How trace is 0 still? I can not use trace estimation now...

Comment: For one thing $W^{1,\infty}_0 \subset W^{1,p}_0$

Comment: And Lipschitz functions are continuous.

Comment: But now W^(1, infty)_0 and W^1,p_0 are defined in different topology, how could you conclude that one is include in another as in your comment? Sorry I'm on my phone